# Meaning of “call by reference”

Tags: programming-languages, semantics, evaluation-strategies

Can someone explain to me in a plain English what call by Reference mean ?
I am having trouble to recognize a difference between "call by value" and "call by reference"

Thank you.

Comment: What part of the Wikipedia article are you having trouble with?

Comment: Here is a serious attempt without referencing Wikipedia or other loud voices.
[Stackoverflow][1]

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71576578/9437799

Answer (score 3):

When you call a function, it gets the arguments.

In math, as well as "pure" functional languages, the function can look at those arguments and compute things based on them, then return a result.

The complication comes from how, in most languages, computation can have side-effects: variables can have their values changed (mutated).

So, for example, if I pass a record/struct to a function and change one of its values, then look at the record after the function has returned, do I still see the changes?

The answer is yes for call by reference, and no for call by value.

Consider the following pseudocode:

```
function foo(bar):
  bar.x = 3
  return bar.x + bar.y

function main:
  myrecord = {x:1, y:2}
  myval = foo(myrecord)
  print myrecord.x
```

What does this program print? 1, or 3?

In call by reference, it prints 3. The function `foo` works on the same piece of memory that `main` works on, so any changes it makes, `main` sees.

In call by value, it prints 1. The "value" of `myrecord` is passed to `foo`, namely a record with 1 and 2 as its fields, but they're not operating on the same piece of memory, so `main` doesn't see any of the changes `foo` makes, because `foo` was just seeing a copy of `myrecord`.